# composer update not pulling latest dev-master

Tags: git, composer-php

I've created two git repositories that we need to install in one of our web applications by using PHP's **composer**. There are two branches on each repository, **master** and **dev-master**.

Inside the project I want the package to install, I've created the following composer.json package configuration:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "proprietary",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "impression-works/pdf-generator",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "git@github.com:...",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "dev-master"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "impression-works/psd-templates",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "git@github.com:...",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "dev-master"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        // ...
        "impression-works/psd-templates": "dev-master",
        "impression-works/pdf-generator": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        // ...
        "psr-0": {
            "ImpressionWorks\\PsdTemplates": "vendor/impression-works/psd-templates/src",
            "ImpressionWorks\\PdfGenerator": "vendor/impression-works/pdf-generator/src"
        }
    },
    // ...
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

When I initially run composer update or composer install, the impression-works packages install perfectly, however, if I make changes to these repositories, and push them to dev-master, any successive calls to composer update simply reports:

```
Nothing to install or update
```

How do I force composer to update to the latest commit on these two custom packages of ours?

Answer (score 27):

I come to this page multiple times a week from a Google search, only to see that it doesn't answer my problem. So here goes.

I'm using packagist.org, not VCS. I do not want to use VCS as it slows Composer even more, and it's already painfully slow.

Consider the following scenario. Application in early development depends on a package I'm building. The package is also early in dev, so dev-master  as version to get the latest master every time.

I fix a critical bug in the package, commit & push it, mash the update button in packagist.org, and then run `composer update`, and absolutely nothing happens.

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

At this point you might try clearing the cache. It doesn't help.

Some point in time you'll stumble upon [this open issue from 2012](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/563). After that you'll find out that the only way to get the latest version installed is to use the commit hash in the require.

---

`composer require vendor/package dev-master#0d7d6c88`

This requires that you manually get the commit hash and update the version to `composer.json`, and then run `composer update` again. Not exactly what you'd expect from a dependency manager. Looks like the issue is never going away, so unless someone writes a better Composer, we're stuck with this behavior.

The alternative is tagging every single commit that you want to download using Composer. Beware of confusing minimum stability rules & errors, which Composer throws by default.

Answer (score 21):

You should rather use custom repositories of type [VCS](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs). The package repo you used has a few limitations as [highlighted in the docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2):

> - Composer will not update the package unless you change the version field.
> - Composer will not update the commit references, so if you use master as reference you will have to delete the package to force an update, and will have to deal with an unstable lock file.

Comment: I experienced the same symptoms as the Asker, but in my case, I hadn't defined a repository for the package at all. To be clear, the package was one of my own, and I host it on a private Git server. I had simply overlooked adding the repository (among the dozens of others I had) before requiring the package. Is it possible that I created the repo in place (or cloned it there manually), and Composer therefor "sees" it and falls-back to the `package` repository type? In any case, this was precisely the solution for me: add the VCS repository for the package to `composer.json`! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I just have had the same problem. After figuring it out, the solution is fairly simple: clean the cache.

What Josef and Christian are looking for can be accomplished with this two lines:

```
composer clearcache
composer upgrade
```

That loads the last repository master for me. Hope it helps the next one, reading this thread.

**Important Note:**

You have to wait for the GitHub service hook to kick in and update the composer package on packagist.org or use the 'Update' button manually on the site.

This is not a matter of seconds... you have to wait for some time (normally one to five minutes) to give packagist a chance to distribute the changes.

So for constant, rapid development, I would just manually `cd vendor/base/package` and `git update`. And from time to time try the above `clearcache` and `upgrade`.

Answer (score 6):

A simpler version than the answer of [@Bitclaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608398/composer-update-not-pulling-latest-dev-master#50243065), for me the following works flawlessly:

```
composer update --prefer-source developer/package
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the cache `composer clearcache` before installing your package.

If the package is already installed, you must remove it. Only after that, clear the cache and install the package again.

Comment: Hi, this question is 5 years old and has 6 copies of the same answer.

Comment: Hi. I just now had this problem and none of the answers helped me. The problem is that if the package is already installed, then just clearing the cache and updating won't help. As it turned out, I needed to remove the package first. I think even today many people can come here with this problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You can suggest an edit to the top answer to add your changes, as it is now all the answers look the same so it is difficult to tell. Additionally, you get reputation and credit if your edit is accepted, in case you are worried about that.

Comment: `composer clearcache` is already suggest as resolution in an [exiting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49692546/367456). This should be an edit or commentary, not a new answer, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

About 9 years late but seeing as this still doesn't have an accepted answer and I also ran into this, although not with my own package but a package I made a PR on and couldn't get the latest commit. From packagist.org:

> New packages will be crawled immediately after submission if you have
> JS enabled.
>
> Existing packages without auto-updating (GitHub/BitBucket/GitLab/Gitea
> hook) will be crawled once a week for updates. When a hook is enabled,
> packages are crawled whenever you push, or at least once a month in
> case the crawl failed. You can also trigger a manual update on your
> package page if you are logged-in as a maintainer.
>
> It is highly recommended to set up the GitHub/BitBucket/GitLab/Gitea
> service hook for all your packages. This reduces the load on our side,
> and ensures your package is updated almost instantly. Check the how-to
> below.
>
> The search index is updated every five minutes. It will index (or
> reindex) any package that has been crawled since the last time the
> search indexer ran.

https://packagist.org/about#how-to-update-packages

If you own the repo you can set up one of the integrations so that every time you push to github it tells packagist to update.

Alternatively, if you need it now you can do what Christian's answer suggests and add the commit sha after the branch name.

Answer (score -2):

Running composer upgrade is a bit dangerous since it may update all the other dependencies you have. In this case I would run the following:

```
composer clearcache;composer update --lock;composer install --prefer-source -vvv
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
composer clear-cache
composer update
```